# Open Microsoft Excel File Using A Web Browser At Desktop Location

Tags: java, web

I am developing a application for automating task and The Server i am using is Tomcat Apache It's based on java. 
                          In between my code execution i have to open a Microsoft Excel At Desktop Level. I have tried Command Line Execution as Well as Desktop Class from AWT.
Both of them works when i execute my app from command line but both of them will not respond when job runs from Web Browser.

Any Comment would be appreciable...

Comment: Have you a given a thought on using selenium??

Comment: You need to show code with your explanations. Its bit confusing this way.

Comment: @HardikSheth i dont know how to use selenium.

Comment: @Ashish I just want to know is it possible to open a desktop application using a browser.

Comment: See selenium 2.0 tutorials on www.seleniumhq.org site and try to implement it in your project because for automation using web browser, it is the best framework I suppose.

Comment: Offcourse it is possible. Web-Browser is a medium for web applications, right ? Now you need to trigger you desktop application(in your case excel), when you perform some action in you web-application. It is difficult without codes. Hope you will get it.

Answer (score 1):

Only an applet on the client side could use the `Desktop` class and it would need full trust to do so. Further, using it would not guarantee either IE or Excel here. An XLS file would be handled by Open Office.

And that is 'a good thing' because *that is my choice* and should not be meddled with by a web-app. that thinks it knows better.

Comment: can you throw some more light or provide a reference so that it helps me in development. Thanks !!!!

Comment: *"provide a reference"*  Reference to what?